What's the difference between ExecuteSqlInterpolated and ExecuteSql?
The difference between with ExecuteSqlRaw is clear, but ExecuteSqlInterpolated and ExecuteSql looks smilar, also in the docs.

Both has the same parameters and output:
public static int ExecuteSqlInterpolated (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, FormattableString sql);
public static int ExecuteSql             (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, FormattableString sql);


Both has the same description: "Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected."

Both has exact the same remarks:


None of them is marked obsolete


The only difference in the docs:
ExecuteSqlInterpolated:

ExecuteSql:

So ExecuteSql is introduced in EF Core 7.
So are these the same and should I use ExecuteSql instead of ExecuteSqlInterpolated for EF Core 7/8 as this one is newer?

In EF Core 7 and later, ExecuteSql has been introduced as a more generic method, whereas ExecuteSqlInterpolated was specifically designed for handling interpolated SQL queries securely in EF Core 3.1. Basically, ExecuteSqlInterpolated uses interpolated string syntax ($"{variableName}") to embed variable values as parameters. This helps prevent SQL injection attacks as the values are properly escaped.
ExecuteSql accepts a plain string for the SQL statement. You would need to manually escape any variable values included within the string to prevent SQL injection.

They are identical: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28609

I started looking at GH issues that contain FromSqlInterpolated and I see quite a bit of confusion, even today. These two methods must exist though, because people will always try to use string interpolation to create the query

Use ExecuteSql.
These two exist for reasons of history and human psychology, to prevent people causing SQL injection issues even though EF makes it trivial to write safe queries because they were too lazy to type Interpolated instead of Raw, or read the docs. I'm pretty sure the relevant GH issues don't use that language though.
As the SQL Queries docs explain :

FromSql was introduced in EF Core 7.0. When using older versions, use FromSqlInterpolated instead.

The same holds for ExecuteSql.
EF Core 2.x: Only FromSQL
EF Core always allowed executing queries with parameters passed as extra values, eg in EF Core 2.0 you could write:
FromSql("select ... where Id=@customerId", customerId);

Different overloads of the same method would accept an interpolated string whose variables were converted into parameters :
FromSql($"select ... where Id={customerId}");

This is needed because people will always try to use interpolated strings to construct queries. By making the method accept FormattableString, the previously unsafe query can be converted into a safe one.
This caused confusion as string interpolation didn't always work as expected. In some cases interpolation occurred instead of parameterization because the C# compiler decided to execute the interpolation:
db.ExecuteSqlCommand(useLogA ?
    $"delete from LogA where Time<{time}" :
    $"delete from LogB where Time<{time}");

In other cases, EF parameterized queries that shouldn't be parameterized:
var sql=$"CREATE USER [{loginName}] FOR LOGIN [{loginName}]"

It was also possible to introduce SQL injection unintentionally, if you extracted a long query into a variable. What you thought was still a FormattableString was now a normal string. I may or may not have done this accidentally too :
var query=$"Big Reporting Query WHERE SaleDate>={date}";

....FromSql(query);

EF Core 3: Two separate methods
In EF Core 3.0 two separate methods were created, FromSqlInterpolated and FromSqlRaw. And guess what some people did .... they started using FromSqlRaw with interpolated strings.
Then some lazy developers started copy-pasta-ing whatever they found in the first Google result, causing SQL injection proliferation in the one platform that makes it trivial to avoid it.
EF Core 7: Alias FromSqlInterpolated as FromSql
Since EF Core 7, the reintroduced FromSql only accepts a FormattableString. It also has 3 fewer letters to type and appears above FromSqlRaw in Intellisense.
The relevant GH issue says :

As discussed offline, we're going to add these, which are identical to FromSqlInterpolated/ExecuteSqlInterpolated. FormattableString is safe from SQL injection attacks, so we generally want to guide users towards doing raw SQL with it, and suffix-less "default" methods would likely be used more by new users etc..
We also considered renaming FromSqlRaw to FromSqlUnsafe to make it clearer that these methods should be used with care, and also removing FromSqlInterpolated/ExecuteSqlInterpolated (obsoleting first). We won't do this since the team decided that the breaking change isn't worth it.


Update
I started looking at GH issues containing FromSqlInterpolated and I see there is still confusion. In that issue someone was trying to format the date parameter:
$@"SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[Orders] 
         WHERE CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE {timeZoneInfo.Id}) 
         = {startDateTime:yyyy-MM-dd}";

Formatting like this makes no sense in SQL and thus isn't supported.
